# ⊢ ((AvB) -> C) -> (A -> C) using simple derivation rules

Tags: logic, deduction

My thought process:

```
- This derivation has no premises.
- The desired conclusion is a conditional, therefore assume 
  the antecedent and derive the conditional.
```

What I have so far:

```
1   1) (AvB) -> C   P
```

I don't know what to do next since there's no easy way to use MP(Modus Ponens) from there.

Comment: What derivation rules are allowed? Natural deduction?

Comment: P, Add, Simp, Conj, MP, PC, RAA @EliranH

Comment: @K.Wong in your comment, you say MP can be used ... in your question you say it can't ...

Comment: @virmaior, in my comment I stated the rules that are ALLOWED. In my question, it is obvious you can't use MP since the rule states that "if we have the sentence A -> B, and we have A, then we can use MP to derive B." We have the sentence "A -> B: (AvB) -> C" but we don't have "A: (AvB)." Therefore the rule MP cannot be used yet.

Comment: @K.Wong okay, I've edited your language to make that clearer... we do from time to time get derivation questions that do not allow MP, and I read your question as saying that.

Comment: @virmaior do you know what step I should take next in solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your goal is ⊢ ((AvB) -> C) -> (A -> C) , you have two different ways of getting there:

(A) Assume (AvB) -> C    assume the left side of  your conditional and get to your end point via CP

(B) Assume ~ ( ((AvB) -> C) -> (A -> C) )  negate the entire of your object then do RAA]

In this case, I think you've made the right choice:

1. | (AvB) -> C)  P

To get to A -> C we can again:

(A) assume the left side and CP

(B) negate the entire expression and RAA

In this case, it's a lot easier to negate -- since we can use addition to show that the negation we make is invalid:

2. | | ~( A -> C)    P
3. | | | A           P
4. | | | A v B       Add 3
5. | | | C           MP 1,4
6. | | A -> C        CP 3-5
7. | A -> C          RAA 2-6
8. ⊢ ((AvB) -> C) -> (A -> C)

(If your proof system requires it, you may need to:

(1) repeat the assumption at line 1 before line 5.

(2) add a conjunction after 7 of 4 and 7 to show the contradiction).

Comment: What are these lines " | ", that are between the numbering and the lettering?

Comment: Layer of assumption. If there were no lines, those would be assumptions given in the problem. (so line 8 has no lines, line 1 has the new assumption (= one), line 2 has a new assumption (= two), line 3 has a new assumption (= three), lines 4-5 still have three, line 6 discharges one by CP (=two), line 7 discharges one by RAA (=one), line discharges one by CP (=zero)).